# Can I recline on my chair?

Tags: usage

**"Can I recline on my chair?"**
Is this sentence correct?

The Bangla word for "recline" is "হেলান দেয়া".

Recline (verb): lean or lie back in a relaxed position with the back supported.

Lounge (verb): lie, sit, or stand in a relaxed or lazy way.

Can you please tell me which word is common for that.

Comment: You *could* use the preposition ***on*** in your context - but as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reclined+on+his+chair%2Creclined+in+his+chair&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creclined%20on%20his%20chair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creclined%20in%20his%20chair%3B%2Cc0) shows, we're much more likely to talk about *reclining **in** a chair*.

Comment: As this Ngram shows, there's not much difference. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reclining+in+a+chair%2Creclining+on+a+chair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creclining%20in%20a%20chair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creclining%20on%20a%20chair%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recline is usually associated with the idea of lifting your feet off the ground and **placing your body in a horizontal or quasi-horizontal position on a surface that can accommodate it**:

In that sense, you can **recline on** a blanket on the grass (**on the ground**); you can **recline on a sofa** (divan or couch); you can **recline on your bed**. And, in some old car advertisements, women were seen **reclining on the hoods of cars**.

Generally, I would not associate reclining with chairs **unless** it is what is called a **chaise-longue** or a **recliner** (those big fat chairs that have footrests that pop up when you lie back in them). That would still be reclining on the chaise-longue or on the recliner.

The only time recline + in might possibly make sense would be to say: reclining in a hammock (though usually it's lying in one) or a **hammock chair**. A hammock chair extends out so that it forms a surface to accommodate your body lying down. In those cases you are actually IN the thing.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can *recline on a chair*, it's valid and will be understood.  (It's not exactly safe, though)

[image]

There is a type of chair that's common called a *recliner* - these are big, comfy chairs in a living room.  The word *recline* with *chair* can strongly imply this.

[image]

Since one tends to sink into such a chair and be surrounded by all sides, it's more common to hear *recline in* a chair.

Comment: You can recline on a couch (sofa) or chaise longue. How do you recline on a regular chair? I just do not associated chairs with reclining. Unless of course the chair is a recliner, as you said.

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/6Mi772 - this is reclining as opposed to sitting.  Also it's possible for 'chair' to mean 'lawn chair' which is definitely reclining.

Comment: I would not call that young man in that chair "reclining" as for me, reclining implies not having one's feet on the ground.....Yes, a lawn chair that is a version of a chaise-longue, you can recline on that.